# Use VPN connection only for selected applications

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, nat, iproute

I am trying to follow: https://superuser.com/a/1262250/41337 but I cannot make it work.

I do:

```
interface=eth0

down() {
    ip netns delete myvpn
    ip link delete vpn0
    iptables -D INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o $interface -j MASQUERADE
}

up() {
    ip netns add myvpn
    ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
    ip netns exec myvpn ip link set lo up
    ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1
    ip link set vpn0 up
    ip link set vpn1 netns myvpn up
    ip addr add 10.200.200.1/24 dev vpn0
    ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 10.200.200.2/24 dev vpn1
    ip netns exec myvpn ip route add default via 10.200.200.1 dev vpn1
    iptables -A INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o $interface -j MASQUERADE
    sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    mkdir -p /etc/netns/myvpn
    echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf
    ip netns exec myvpn ping 8.8.8.8
}

down
up
```

In another terminal I run:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni any host 8.8.8.8
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:49:44.817183 vpn0  In  IP 10.200.200.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 18314, seq 1, length 64
22:49:45.822772 vpn0  In  IP 10.200.200.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 18314, seq 2, length 64
22:49:46.842785 vpn0  In  IP 10.200.200.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 18314, seq 3, length 64
```

This leads me to believe there is a step missing: Network traffic does not go out on eth0.

These all work:

```
ip netns exec myvpn ping 10.200.200.1
ip netns exec myvpn ping 10.200.200.2
ping 10.200.200.2
```

This fails:

```
ping 10.200.200.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This command...

```
ip netns exec myvpn ip route add default via 10.200.200.1 dev vpn1
```

...should fail with:

```
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

Because you never set interface `vpn1` `up` (so `10.200.200.1` is not reachable). You should do this immediately after assigning an address:

```
ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 10.200.200.2/24 dev vpn1
ip netns exec myvpn ip link set vpn1 up
```

---

The following script works for me. This is almost identical to your script, with the following changes:

- I have added the missing `ip set link up` command noted earlier
- I have replaced all instances of `ip netns exec myvpn ip ...` with `ip -n myvpn ...`
- I have taken advantage of the `netns` argument to `ip link add`

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=eth0

down() {
    ip netns delete myvpn
    ip link delete vpn0
    iptables -D INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o $interface -j MASQUERADE
}

up() {
    ip netns add myvpn
    ip -n myvpn addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
    ip -n myvpn link set lo up
    ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1 netns myvpn
    ip link set vpn0 up
    ip addr add 10.200.200.1/24 dev vpn0
    ip -n myvpn addr add 10.200.200.2/24 dev vpn1
    ip -n myvpn link set vpn1 up
    ip -n myvpn route add default via 10.200.200.1 dev vpn1
    iptables -A INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o $interface -j MASQUERADE
    ip netns exec myvpn ping -c 10 8.8.8.8
}

sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

down
trap down EXIT
up
```

Running this script on my system produces:

```
Cannot remove namespace file "/var/run/netns/myvpn": No such file or directory
Cannot find device "vpn0"
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=9.80 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=15.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=9.06 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=8.27 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=116 time=11.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=116 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=116 time=7.21 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.211/11.621/15.819/2.871 ms
```

Comment: You expect those errors, because when you first run the script you have not created the namespace nor any iptables rules, so the attempts to delete those things will fail. You can see those errors in the output I show in this answer.

Comment: If you're running the script in my answer, you will see those errors every time because the script cleans things up when it exits (via the `trap down EXIT` command).